# java.security file in ANT

Tags: java, security, ant

How can I force Ant to use my java.security file?  I'm trying to build with Ant from a command line and use this file in the JVM.  Is there any way to do this via Ant command line?

Is setting an environment variable ANT_OPTS the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, set `ANT_OPTS=-Djava.security.policy=file:./java.policy` is works for me